# Vertical Slider of Angular Material does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I use Angular Material for my application. It works fine if there is no content above it. But when I put some content and the scroll bar appear, it goes wrong when dragging.

**Working example:**

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.vol = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    $scope.bass = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    $scope.master = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.0-rc.5/docs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.js"></script>

<!-- remove this -->
<p>My content</p>
<p>My content</p>
<p>My content</p>
<p>My content</p>
<p>My content</p>
<p>My content</p>
<!-- remove this -->

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="sliderdemoVertical" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content layout="row" layout-padding="">
    <md-slider-container flex="">
      <md-input-container>
        <input flex="" type="number" ng-model="vol" aria-label="volume" aria-controls="volume-slider">
      </md-input-container>
      <md-slider ng-model="vol" min="0" max="100" aria-label="volume" id="volume-slider" class="md-accent" md-vertical="" md-range=""></md-slider>
      
      <h5>Volume</h5>
    </md-slider-container>
    <md-slider-container flex="">
      <md-input-container>
        <input flex="" type="number" ng-model="bass" aria-label="bass" aria-controls="bass-slider">
      </md-input-container>
      <md-slider md-discrete="" ng-model="bass" min="0" max="100" step="10" aria-label="bass" class="md-primary" md-vertical=""></md-slider>
      
      <h5>Bass</h5>
    </md-slider-container>
    <div flex="" layout="column" layout-align="center center">
      <md-slider-container ng-disabled="readonly">
        <md-input-container>
          <input flex="" type="number" ng-model="master" aria-label="master" aria-controls="master-slider">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-slider flex="" ng-model="master" md-discrete="" aria-label="Master" md-vertical="" step="10" ng-readonly="readonly"></md-slider>
        <h5>Master</h5>
      </md-slider-container>
      <md-checkbox ng-model="readonly">Read only</md-checkbox>
    </div>
  </md-content>
</div>

<!--
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be in foundin the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/license.
-->
```

Same sample as above in Codepen: [here](http://codepen.io/than1089/pen/wWGXxR)

If you remove all content in HTML and there is no scroll bar, it works fine.

Is that a bug from Angular Material or I did something wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: there's no code sample. maybe you forgot to add it? :/

Comment: Sorry, I can not add the codepen link to the post. I mange to edit the post content. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: The question should contain the relevant code directly instead of linking to an external resource. Links can become broken and then the question has no value anymore for future visitors.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess the problem comes from the offset to document of the mouse event. But not sure why it works here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/slider

Answer (score 0):

When I work with `angular-material` I needed a slider too and I used [angular-jk-carousel](https://github.com/juank11memphis/angular-jk-carousel). Its works fine with angular-material. For the scroll bar issue if you have navbar you should include your navbar to main container I think.